# how to open screen on full screen

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can open my asp.net program on full screen (like i press F11)

Through C# code ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","window.open('Default.aspx','','fullscreen=yes')");
```

not exactly full screen  but pretty similar

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this.](http://onetidbit.wordpress.com/2008/03/06/full-screen-with-javascript-in-aspnet/) Instead of linking, you can redirect your user from your default page with the proper javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can send a F11 key pressed command from your application once it's loaded to force your browser to go full screen?

I doubt if there is a clean way of doing this as the F11 fullscreen command is handled by your internet browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is talking about asp.net application so the "program" here  is browser.

If it is true, you need client-side javascript to do that. something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
top.window.moveTo(0,0); 
if (document.all)
    { top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight); } 
else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) { 
    if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth)
    { 
        top.window.outerHeight = top.screen.availHeight; 
            top.window.outerWidth = top.screen.availWidth; 
    } 
 } 
</script>
```

- document.all works for Internet Explorer while document.layers works for Other browsers.
- top refers to the window that is on top of all other windows in the window object hierarchy.
- top.window.moveTo(0,0) will display the top window at these coordinates ie. the upper left corner of the screen.
- resizeTo(x,y) will resize the window to the size specified.
- availWidth and availHeight are properties of the screen object which can detect the available screen space.

Hope this helps...